# How meteor know what document "this" refers to in the event

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Im having it difficult to understand how when i add events to a certain template, "this" know what document and collection to refer to.

Example:

```
Template.game.events({ 
  "click a.one-plus": function(event, template){ 
     event.preventDefault();
     Games.update({_id:this._id}, {$inc:{
       "teams.0.score":1
     }});
  },
});
```

Comment: When meteor calls your function, it defines what `this` refers to. You can think about it as a hidden parameter that has a default value which you can change, e.g. clickFunction.call(customThis, arg1, arg2, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` will refer to the context associated with the template (or template fragment) where the event is triggered.

Let's say your template is like this:

```
<template name='myTemplate'>
   <button id='myButton'/>
   {{#each myList}}
       <button class='mySecondButton'/>
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

And you've defined

```
Template.helpers({
  myList() {
     return [1,2,3];
  }
});
```

Then the context for a `click` on `myButton` will contain `this.myList()`. (If you use a `Router`, you will probably use a different way to 'bind' data to your template.)

Be careful though: in the `each` iteration, the context changes to the current iterator element. So `this` will be respectively `1`, `2` and `3` in this case, so the three `.mySecondButton` buttons will see a different context. `each` changes the context, so does `with`.